# Sort data in varchar alphabet order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with following data .

```
 1
 AAAAA01 
 AAAAA01
 AAAAA01
 B21
 AAAAAA1
 B3
 AB100
```

and I want to sort data in following order

```
 AAAAAA1
 AAAAA01
 AAAAA01
 AAAAA01
 AB100
 B21
 B3
 1
```

I wrote a statement but not give me correct result.

```
    Select
    *
from
    dbo.Section
order by      
    CASE    
      WHEN not Section like '%[^0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(int,Section)
      WHEN  Section like '[0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(Section,1,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',Section)-900000))
    END
```

For your help i am providing script of table

```
  INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'1')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'AAAAA01')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'AAAAA01')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'AAAAA01')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'AAAAA01')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'AAAAA01')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'B21')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'AAAAAA1')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'B3')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'AB100')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'2')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'B1')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'B32')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'11')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'A10')
INSERT [dbo].[Section] ([Section]) VALUES (N'ABAAAA')
```

Can you please tell me how can this provide me correct answer.

Comment: Your  table is `Section` and column also name `Section`?

Comment: @lad2025 table name and column name both are section

Comment: Can you describe, with words, the wanted sorting?

Comment: @jarlh want to sort what start from A and go through all A. After that B ...Z

Comment: @jarlh after this if any number with character lijke All AAAAA then AAAAAA1 , then AAAAA01 after end all character start form 1 so in my example 1 in last position

Comment: Please provide correct results for new data or check is suggested query returns right result here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d37e1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
Select    
    *
from
    dbo.Section
order by
    REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE
    (REPLACE ([Section], '0', 'ZZ0'),
    '1', 'ZZ1'),
    '2', 'ZZ2'),
    '3', 'ZZ3'),
    '4', 'ZZ4'),
    '5', 'ZZ5'),
    '6', 'ZZ6'),
    '7', 'ZZ7'),
    '8', 'ZZ8'),
    '9', 'ZZ9'),
    [Section]
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d37e1/4)

Result of select for new test data:
[image]

Please check is it correct to you.

Comment: All result are coming fine but problem in B After B1 the result will be B1- B21 - B3 -  B32 match sort from left to right excepted B... all are coming right . @Stepan Novikov

Comment: thanks i am doing up mark your answer . Please up mark my question if you like my quesiton

Comment: one small question what is replace (replace (replace means in you query

Comment: It means replacing one string with another string

Answer (score 1):

This is another way. Assuming your number strings are greater than -100000000.

```
SELECT YourString
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourString LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 
                        CONVERT(int, YourString) ELSE -100000000  END, YourString
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to split your field in two, alpha and num. In order to order the query by Alpha, first and Num, second.
But `AAAAA1` is after `AAAA01` with my logic... Do you have an explicite rule to explain why do you want `AAAA01` before `AAAAA1` ?

```
SELECT SECTION.section,
        CASE
            WHEN section NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]'
            THEN section
            WHEN section LIKE '[A-Z]%'
            THEN
               LEFT (section, PATINDEX ('%[^A-Z]%', section)-1)                  
            ELSE
            'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
         END
            AS Alpha,
            CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(section)=1 
            THEN CAST( section AS int)
            WHEN SECTION.section LIKE '%[0-9]'
            THEN
               CAST( RIGHT (section, PATINDEX ('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE (section))-1 ) AS INT)
            ELSE
               0       
         END
            AS Num

    FROM SECTION
ORDER BY Alpha, Num;
```

[Please see the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1a03/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about this SQL? i tried with your data and it's returned the correct order

```
SELECT section
FROM section
ORDER BY LEN(LEFT(Section, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Section)-1)) DESC
```

**Responding to @A.Goutam's comment below (i'm sorry i don't know how to add image to the comment)**

I just copied the data given by @A.Goutam and tried it directly in my sql server as shown below

[image]

New SQL query with new data

```
SELECT section AS section
FROM section
ORDER BY LEN(section + '1') DESC
    , LEN(LEFT(section + '1', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', section + '1')-1)) DESC
    , CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(section + '1',PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',section + '1'),LEN(section + '1'))) DESC
```

Result:

```
AAAAAA1
AAAAA01
AAAAA01
AAAAA01
AAAAA01
AAAAA01
ABAAAA
AB100
B32
B21
A10
B3
B1
11
2
1
```

Comment: @Faithir Mohamad `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. ` sorry this error

Comment: It is working perfect for the given set of values by @A.Goutam

Comment: Hi @A.Goutam could you please take a screenshot of your query as i gave on my edited post?

Comment: @FathirMohamad i hv add table insert script in question plz run this into your table

Comment: @A.Goutam i have add new query. please check whether it's match with your need

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you're trying to get with temporary table as well. However, for larger records this can add some overhead to performance. So, i suggest you to use it sparingly.

```
CREATE table #temp
(
    Section varchar(20)
)
INSERT INTO #temp
   SELECT * FROM dbo.Section WHERE section LIKE '[A-Z]%' order by section ASC
INSERT INTO #temp
   SELECT * FROM dbo.Section WHERE section LIKE '[0-9]%' order by section ASC

SELECT * FROM #temp
drop table #temp
```